# django easy-thumbnail not working, pillow isn't causing it

Tags: django, thumbnails

I'm not sure why it's not working

settings file

```
THUMBNAIL_DEBUG = True
THUMBNAIL_ALIASES = {
    'image': {
        'standard': {
            'size': (70, 70),
            'crop': True,
        }
    }
}
```

Index.html
I load thumbnail 
then

```
 <img src="{{ post.image|thumbnail_url:'standard' }}" alt=""/></img>
```

Comment: can you define what `it's not working` is? no image is showing up? any error?

Comment: no error, it's just simply not working not showing image. without thumbnail it shows the image but without it's not

Comment: I assume image is an ImageField in the post model? If so maybe try {% thumbnail post.image %}?

Comment: @Paulo using easy_thumbnail? put {% thumbnail post.image %} insteady of {{ post.image|thumbnail_url:'standard' }}??

Comment: Do you have imaging libraries installed correctly on your computer? That normally is the first thing I'd check.

Comment: @haloyoba yes. You can pass options to the thumbnail tag like {% thumbnail post.image 300x200 %}

Answer (score 0):

I never used `THUMBNAIL_ALIASES` but this way always worked for me:

```
{% load thumbnail %}

{% thumbnail post.image as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

btw, your `img` tag is wrong.

Comment: it's not working for me but are you using easy thumbnail?

Comment: oh sorry, I thought you are using sorl-thumbnail :) actually sorl.thumbnail is also not bad @haloyoba

Comment: yeah I'm checking out sorl thumbnail actually, it almost works it shows thumbnail but not the image...I had this problem when I didn't upload pillow right but this time I have right version....not sure why it's not working

Comment: are you saying my img tag is wrong because put </img> at the end?

Comment: @haloyoba yes, </img> is too much