# easy thumbnail, without thumbnail image works but with thumbnail, nothing shows up

Tags: django, easy-thumbnails

my image is displayed without thumbnail functionality, but as soon as I put thumbnail I get nothing.

I'm using easy thumbnail, I followed the documentation mainly. 
In  template

```
{% load thumbnail %}
<img src="{{post.image|thumbnail_url:'avatar'}}" alt="" />
```

In setting

```
THUMBNAIL_ALIASES = {
    '': {
        'avatar': {'size': (50, 50), 'crop': True},
    },
    }
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521778/django-easy-thumbnail-not-working-pillow-isnt-causing-it

Comment: @Paulo I couldn't find the solution, do you know the solution